# How can I combine multiple images into one page and print it as a pdf?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I've a webpage with 4 charts. I'm taking separate screenshots for each of them. Then tried to put them on another canvas, show them vertically and print it as single-page pdf file. But, I'm getting an Error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage: Argument 1
> could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, SVGImageElement,
> HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.

### Here is the script

```js
function HTMLtoPDF() {

    function verticalCanvases(cnv1, cnv2, cnv3, cnv4) {
        var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d'),
            width = cnv1.width,
            height = cnv1.height + cnv2.height + cnv3.height + cnv4.height;
    
        newCanvas.width = width;
        newCanvas.height = height;
    
        [{
            cnv: cnv1,
            y: 0
        },
        {
            cnv: cnv2,
            y: cnv1.height
        },
        {
            cnv: cnv3,
            y: cnv1.height + cnv2.height
        },
        {
            cnv: cnv4,
            y: cnv1.height + cnv2.height + cnv3.height

        }].forEach(function(n) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.drawImage(n.cnv, 0, n.y, width, n.cnv.height);
        });
    
         var imgdata = newCanvas.toDataURL();

        return imgdata;
    }

    var forms = $('[id^=caspioform]');

    var canvas1 = html2canvas(forms[3]);
    var canvas2 = html2canvas(forms[5]);
    var canvas3 = html2canvas(forms[7]);
    var canvas4 = html2canvas(forms[9]);

    var dURL = verticalCanvases(canvas1, canvas2, canvas3, canvas4);

    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");

    var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

    doc.addImage(dURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, width, height);

    doc.save('sample.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Hi there, looks like your canvas data can not be rendered by a canvas element, it means that you probably are getting the html canvas instead to retrieve the inner cavas context, try to render canvas context instead the canvas html element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't mention it, I'll assume `html2canvas` is coming from https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas

In that case, the issue here is that `hmtl2canvas` returns a `Promise` and that's what you're passing to `verticalCanvases` instead of the actual canvas element.

To fix it just transform the function in an asynchronous one so you can use `async`/`await`:

```
// |
// |
// v
async function HTMLtoPDF() {

    function verticalCanvases(cnv1, cnv2, cnv3, cnv4) {
        var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d'),
            width = cnv1.width,
            height = cnv1.height + cnv2.height + cnv3.height + cnv4.height;
    
        newCanvas.width = width;
        newCanvas.height = height;
    
        [{
            cnv: cnv1,
            y: 0
        },
        {
            cnv: cnv2,
            y: cnv1.height
        },
        {
            cnv: cnv3,
            y: cnv1.height + cnv2.height
        },
        {
            cnv: cnv4,
            y: cnv1.height + cnv2.height + cnv3.height

        }].forEach(function(n) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.drawImage(n.cnv, 0, n.y, width, n.cnv.height);
        });
    
         var imgdata = newCanvas.toDataURL();

        return imgdata;
    }

    var forms = $('[id^=caspioform]');

    var canvas1 = await html2canvas(forms[3]); // <--
    var canvas2 = await html2canvas(forms[5]); // <--
    var canvas3 = await html2canvas(forms[7]); // <--
    var canvas4 = await html2canvas(forms[9]); // <--

    var dURL = verticalCanvases(canvas1, canvas2, canvas3, canvas4);

    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");

    var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

    doc.addImage(dURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, width, height);

    doc.save('sample.pdf');
}
```